# MongooseJs query using $in or Promise.all?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongoose

i just want to ask a question
Lets say i have an array of ids thats 1 to 10000

```
[1, 2, 3, 4....... 10000]
```

Now i want to get all data, which is fast or much performant or more advisable to do?

```
await Promise.all(
  usersIds.map(async userId => dbCollection.users.findById(userId))
);
```

or

```
dbCollection.users.find({
  _id: {$in: usersIds} 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you'll want to use `$in` rather than `Promise.all` -- it reduces the amount of network back-and-forth that you have to do, won't fully saturate your connection pool (if you're using connection pooling), and ends up being roughly the same amount of work in mongo.

Assuming you actually have `userIds` that are `1..10000`, using `$gte` and `$lte` will be even faster because you'll end up with a better query plan (the mongo query planner isn't smart enough to do this on its own).

Comment: If you wanted to get even faster, you could chunk `userIds` into X queries where X is less than the number of open connections in your connection pool